# how to give command line to run browser which in turn runs php script

Tags: php, internet-explorer

question is how to give command line (in .cmd script) to execute browser to then in turn have browser execute .php script.

Presently if from a command window I execute like ...

"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" file:\c:\users\win7ultsdtest\findroot.php
....OR....
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore c:\users\win7ultsdtest\findroot.php

This will run the Explorer browser, but then the browser the browser will download the contents of findroot.php instead of executing the php code as I need.  Does anyone know how I can get the browser to instead execute the php code and not just download it as data?

Let me explain my need ... The findroot.php file contains php code to access the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable.  This variable is ONLY non-null when the localhost is running a http server and then it contains the localhost document server root path where loadable browser .html, .php etc may be stored to loaded from http:\ lines.

The findroot.php outputs the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] contents to a file as rootpath.txt so that my .cmd script can then can automatically install PHP code into the active PHP servers document root area.

So understand I must find the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] from a .cmd script.
Now I might search ALL the computers drives for httpd.conf and then scan that file for the value but this wouldn't work for two reasons; 1. there can be multiple httpd.conf files and I can't know which server is active and using what httpd.conf.  2. it would take a long time to search a given computers entire drive(s) on all httpd.conf files.

Comment: You need a webserver to execute your php page - your browser doesn't know how to handle php because it's server side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

The browser won't execute PHP code. You either need a server to run PHP and to access it via HTTP such as `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore http://localhost/url/for/findroot.php` or you can run PHP via the command line `c:\path\to\php.exe c:\users\win7ultsdtest\findroot.php`. However running it via the command line won't give you $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as that is only populated when running PHP within a server.

It's not possible to execute PHP by the HTTP server without the server knowing about the PHP before hand - for example, by being in the document root. Of course if you don't know the document root, your script won't be there. If you're trying to install a script into a web server for a user, it's much better to give instructions on how to do so as their server environment will likely vary from what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, it APPEARS unfortunately we can't fully automate an example because we can't determine from a .cmd script where the DOCUMENT ROOT is.  We have PHP5 TestCoverage and Timing Profiling Utilities which are very nice in capability we are just now trying to make them as user friendly as possible by adding a good example.  We want to provide an example .cmd script which takes some PHP source, instruments copies and instruments source, runs the PHP and shows the GUI and XML reports. Also the way our instrumentation works it MUST have a folder under the Document Root to run it's PHP code in.

Answer (score -1):

There are light browsers like lynx if you are in a linux machine

lynx http://whateverurl/php.php